# Why do these dots get displaced vertically with ListPlot?

Tags: plotting

Why do these dots get displaced vertically with `ListPlot`?

```
Show[
ListPlot[Sin@Range[0,2\[Pi],0.2],Filling->Axis,DataRange->{0,2\[Pi]},PlotStyle->{Thick,Red}],
Plot[Sin[t],{t,0,2\[Pi]}]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I think I got the solution. The `Range` step must be a fraction of `Pi`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
range = Range[0, 2 π, .2]; 

MinMax[range] (* is not quite {0, 2Pi} *)
```

> ```
> {0., 6.2}
> ```

```
Show[ListPlot[Sin@range, Filling -> Axis, DataRange -> MinMax[range], 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[{Thick, Red}]], 
 Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 2 π}]]
```

[image]